# geth testnet struck at block number 638910

Tags: testnets

I am using geth, initially blocks I am having are continuously behind what I can see at https://testnet.etherscan.io/. I am using ubuntu, and I start ethereum by giving the command :geth --testnet console

If I give miner.start() command on the console it is mining and I am getting the mining reward as well. But the output of eth.blockNumber is behind the latest block mined on https://testnet.etherscan.io/

Moreover my coinbase address is 0x78ca58da3b0b4d518aeafd846568dcd5286c1cf7, if I search for this account number, there is no transactions and ether balance is zero, where as eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0]).toNumber() on geth console show the output as 6.680659680388181e+21.

Edit: Now I am struck at block number 638910, and getting the message
"I0306 10:22:38.903148 eth/downloader/downloader.go:723] Peer bf7ecea3f90155d9 [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: potential rewrite attack: #548910 [00000000…] <= #548910 limit"

Not able to understand the issue? please guide.

Comment: Ropsten is pretty much dead, see the linked thread for details.